# What determines the android-minSdkVersion in Cordova?

Tags: cordova, phonegap

I can build and run on my Samsung Note 4, but I can't build on my older HTC Desire C. Without rooting it, I can't raise the operating system above Android 4.0.3, API 15. My Cordova build settings seem to set the android-minSdkVersion at 16. How do I decrease it down ?

Answer (score 1):

The minimum SDK version is specified in the **AndroidManifest.xml** inside your "platforms > android > CordovaLib" directory in your Cordova project. The specific line looks like,

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" />
```

However in my experience, even if we reduce this MinSDKVersion the app doesn't support old versions of Android most of the time. So the solution is using a Cordova version targeted at an old **TargetSDKVersion**.

Refer this link, you can see all the Cordova release versions.

[Cordova release versions](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/releases)

For example if you use a version like Cordova Android 7.1.4 which is targeted at Android API level 27 (8.1 Oreo) it won't work in old versions of Android like Lollipop, but as I have tested the minimum working Android version for that is 7.0 Nougat though it's targeted at 8.1 Oreo.

So, what you have to do is use an old Cordova release **targeted** at an old Android version and find what works for your need.
You can specify the Cordova Android version while adding Android platform as,

```
cordova platform add android@x.x.x
```